# Nested Lists from HackerRank

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x

I am a beginner in python. This is the [Nested Lists](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/nested-list/problem) problem from HaackerRank.

> Given the names and grades for each student in a Physics class of N
>   students, store them in a nested list and print the name(s) of any
>   student(s) having the second lowest grade.
>
> Note: If there are multiple students with the same grade, order their
>   names alphabetically and print each name on a new line.

I want to improve my code with better functions available in python and I want to decrease lines of code.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    scorecard = []
    for _ in range(int(input())):
        name = input()
        score = float(input())
        scorecard.append([name, score])
    scorecard.sort(key = lambda x:x[1])
    names = []
    lowest_score = scorecard[0][1]
    second_lowest = 0
    for i in range(len(scorecard)):
        if scorecard[i][1] > lowest_score and second_lowest == 0:
            second_lowest = scorecard[i][1]

        if second_lowest != 0 and scorecard[i][1] == second_lowest:
            names.append(scorecard[i][0])

    names.sort()

    for name in names:
    print(name)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. I'd recommend separating the logic of getting the user input from the logic of building and sorting the nested list.
2. Your code doesn't build a nested list in a way that's useful for solving the problem; I think what you want is a list of lists of names, where each list of names corresponds to a grade.
3. Any time you want to group things into buckets (e.g. all the names that go with a grade), it's a good time to use a dictionary!
4. Using list comprehensions is frequently a good way to express a loop in a shorter way.
5. Type annotations make it easier to keep track of what your code is doing (and they let you use `mypy` to catch bugs).

Here's my solution that uses a separate function to build the nested list, using a dictionary as an intermediate step to collect all the names for a given grade.  Note that the type annotations tell you exactly where the names (strings) and grades (floats) are going at each step!

```
from collections import defaultdict
from typing import Dict, List, Tuple

def build_grade_lists(grades: List[Tuple[str, float]]) -> List[List[str]]:
    """
    Given a list of (name, grade) tuples, return a list of names for each grade.
    Each list is sorted, i.e.:
        the top level list is sorted from lowest to highest grade
        each list of names is sorted alphabetically
    """
    grade_lists: Dict[float, List[str]] = defaultdict(list)
    for name, grade in grades:
        grade_lists[grade].append(name)
    return [sorted(grade_lists[grade]) for grade in sorted(list(grade_lists.keys()))]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    scorecard = [(input(), float(input())) for _ in range(int(input()))]
    for name in build_grade_lists(scorecard)[1]:
        print(name)
```

Comment: 2  small improvements: your function can accept any finite `Iterable[Tuple[str, float]]`, not just lists, and `[sorted(names) for _, names in sorted(grade_list.items())]` expresses the final result clearer in my opinion.